# hook_mail is not sending rendered HTML email

Tags: 8

I'm rendering HTML template for email

**demo_test.module**

```
use Drupal\Component\Utility\SafeMarkup;

function demo_test_theme() {   return [
    'contact_mail' => [
      'variables' => ['params' => NULL],
    ]   
  ]; 
}

function demo_test_mail($key, &$message, $params) {

  $render_email = [
    '#theme' => 'contact_email',
    '#params' => $params,   ];

  $mail = drupal_render($render_email);

  $message['body'][] = $mail;   
  break; 
}
```

**contact_mail.html.twig**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #ff0000;
        background-color: #FAFAFA;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>test</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Tried:

```
$message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes';
```

But still not working.

Comment: You could use mail system module https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem

Comment: Hi @Kstack need to use that module for this? Can't achieve via code changes?

Comment: @Mike Drupals default mail backend will convert any HTML to plain text. Look at [PhpMail::format](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Mail%21Plugin%21Mail%21PhpMail.php/function/PhpMail%3A%3Aformat/). You could achieve the desired result by writing your own mail system but that would require quite a lot of effort, especially if you want to send as both HTML and Plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same what you done above. Using `hook_mail_alter` function will not work for this case either.

Better is to use [Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/MimeMail) module to achieve this HTML Format.

> It permits users to receive HTML email and can be used by other modules. The mail functionality accepts an HTML message body, mime-endcodes it and sends it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Swift Mailer module](https://www.drupal.org/project/swiftmailer).

One of the feature includes sending HTML (MIME) e-mails.

> The module also lets you theme e-mails so that they reflect the general look and feel of your site and at the same time appear correctly in various e-mail clients. Images required by the theme can be attached to the e-mail and displayed inline.